# Search for file names that contain words from a list and have a certain file extension

Tags: python, search, os.walk, contain

Beginner at python. I'm trying to search users folders for illegal content saved in folders. I want to find all files that contain either one or a number of words from the below list and also the files also have an extension that's listed.

I can search the files using file.endswith but don't know how to add in the word condition.

I've looked through the site and how only come across how to search for a certain word and not a list of words.

Thank you in advance

```
import os
L = ['720p','aac','ac3','bdrip','brrip','demonoid','disc','hdtv','dvdrip',
        'edition','sample','torrent','www','x264','xvid']

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Y:\User Folders\"):
    for file in files:

            if file.endswith(('*.7z','.3gp','.alb','.ape','.avi','.cbr','.cbz','.cue','.divx','.epub','.flac',
                              '.flv','.idx','.iso','.m2ts','.m2v','.m3u','.m4a','.m4b','.m4p','.m4v','.md5',
                              '.mkv','.mobi','.mov','.mp3','.mp4','.mpeg','.mpg','.mta','.nfo','.ogg','.ogm',
                              '.pla','.rar','.rm','.rmvb','.sfap0','.sfk','.sfv','.sls','.smfmf','.srt,''.sub',
                              '.torrent','.vob','.wav','.wma','.wmv','.wpl','.zip')):

                    print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: Do you want to detect forbidden words in file name or file content? I assume you care about the word in file name.

Comment: `for tag in L: if tag in file:`?

Comment: @JanVlcinsky Hi Jan, yes I'm looking to detect the forbidden words in the filename.

Comment: @jDo added that in seems to be working. It's only finding files that contain a tag and has one of the file extensions stated. Only thing is that it's very slow in its search.

Answer (score 0):

## Using `py.path.local` from `py` package

The `py` package (install by `$ pip install py`) offers a very nice interface for working with files.

```
from py.path import local


def isbadname(path):
    bad_extensions = [".pyc", "txt"]
    bad_names = ["code", "xml"]
    return (path.ext in bad_extensions) or (path.purebasename in bad_names)


for path in local(".").visit(isbadname):
    print(path.strpath)
```

Explained:

Import

```
from py.path import local
```

`py.path.local` function creates "objectified" file names. To keep my code short, I import
it this way to use only `local` for objectifying file name strings.

Create objectified path to local directory:

```
local(".")
```

Created object is not a string, but an object, which has many interesting properties and methods.

Listing all files within some directory:

```
local(".").visit("*.txt")
```

returns a generator, providing all paths to files having extension `".txt".`.

Alternative method to detect files to generate is providing a function, which gets argument `path`
(objectified file name) and returns `True` if the file is to be used, `False` otherwise.

The function `isbadname` serves exactly this purpose.

If you want to google for more information, use **py path local** (the name `py` is not giving good hits).

For more see https://py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/path.html

Note, that if you use `pytest` package, the `py` is installed with it (for good
reason - it makes tests related to file names much more readable and shorter).

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a go now. After I complete my search and gather a list of file names, is there a way of deleting them then?

Comment: @Jason Sure, That is the beauty of `py.path.local`. Having the file object, do `path.remove()`. Check the docs, you will like that (more methods for `copy`, `rename`, `exists` etc. are present.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it might be better to do a reverse search, and display a warning about files that DON'T match the file types you want. For instance you could do this:

```
if file.endswith(".txt", ".py"):
  print("File is ok!")
else:
  print("File is not ok!")
```